# Add custom SpamAssassin rules to e-mail header

Tags: email, spam-prevention, spamassassin

Is there a way to configure SpamAssassin to show any custom rules that an e-mail matches in the incoming headers, as the built-in rules do?

For example, I have the following:

```
Content analysis details:   (0.1 points, 4.1 required)

pts rule name              description
```

---

```
-0.1 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW      RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, low
                         trust
                         [209.85.220.68 listed in list.dnswl.org]
1.0 FREEMAIL_FROM          Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail provider
                         (eellibrown[at]gmail.com)
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
-1.1 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2      RBL: Average reputation (+2)
                         [209.85.220.68 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                         domain
0.5 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
X-Spam-Flag: NO
```

All of those rules are pre-defined.  I have some custom rules that *should* also match, which are defined in my local SpamAssassin config file.  I am not sure if the custom rules are being applied, since I do not see them listed in the header with the pre-defined ones, and the score does not reflect my custom rules.

However, if I change the scoring of the pre-defined rules in my local configuration, the new scores are applied correctly.  My server support tells me that they have enabled the local custom rules, but I am still seeing spam which in my opinion should be blocked, that as far as I can tell matches some of my rules.

Basically, a few of our company's e-mail address have somehow gotten on some e-mail lists and they receive hundreds of spam e-mails a day.  This makes it difficult to find the non-spam messages, which are a handful a day.  I have been trying to make custom rules to reduce the amount of spam, but if I can not be sure my rules are being applied, I don't know how to ensure that any new rules I make or modify will actually block anything.

I am open to suggestions of other methods of blocking the spam as well, other than just getting new e-mail addresses for everyone (although that would be nice).

Comment: Custom rules are normally displayed in headers. Presumably in your case they're ignored upper in the chain of events.

Comment: Any suggestion as to where I might check?  It is on a shared server, so the rules are not global, but as I mentioned in the post - the custom scoring of the default rules are being applied, so it appears that my local config is being recognized at least.

Comment: It looks like my rules are now showing in the headers.  The spamassassin process needed to be reloaded in order for the changes to take effect.